# laravel eloquent for hasMany relation does not work

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have these relations in my database

```
Schema::create('my_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('fullName');
        $table->string('userName');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('photo');
        $table->string('email');
    });
```

and

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('photo');
        $table->text('caption');
        $table->integer('like');
        $table->integer('my_user_id');
    });
```

my models :

```
class myUser extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\post');
    }        

}
 class post extends Model
    {
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\myUser');
        }


}
```

now I'm trying to get a user's data using the following code :

```
$post = post::find(1);        
$user =  $post->user;
```

but it doesn't work and $user is NULL.
I'm sure that in posts table there is a record with id 1.
the weird part is this that I get no error when I change the method's name like this :

```
$post = post::find(1);        
$user =  $post->somethingBullshit;
```

I'm using laravel 5.3.

help please.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I already had this issue. I think it's because of the name of your "post" class. Try to rename the model and the table for something like "myPost" and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you are naming your class files starting with upper case letters, and modify your class declarations accordingly, such as:

```
class MyUser extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }        
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MyUser');
    }
}
```

You can then select the user when you obtain the post by utilizing [eloquent's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `with()` method, and obtain your `$user` variable from your `$post` variable, OR just use the user property of post as follows:

```
$post = Post::with('user')->find(1); 
$user = $post->user;
```

Comment: I'm also sure that the related user record exists.

Comment: if you return $post does it contain the information you are expecting or is it also empty/NULL?

Comment: No $post is ok with expected data.

Comment: @blank94 modified answer

Comment: No result is the same still.It's too simple problem but I have no idea what is wrong :(